# in mongodb, whats the easiest way to get an array of a single field from the documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Assume, I have these documents in my collection:

```
{
  _id: xxx,
  region: "sw"
},
{
  _id: yyy,
  region: "nw"
}
```

I want to end up with an array like this:

```
['sw', 'nw']
```

I have tried mongodb aggregation/group and mapreduce but I always end up with an array of documents that then have to be looped through again to get to a single array.  Is there a way to achieve this in a single mongodb query or will it always require a query and then further processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    {$group: {_id: null, region: {$push: "$region"}}}
).result[0].region
```

Or if you want to use map-reduce:

```
db.foo.mapReduce(
    function() { emit(null, this.region)},
    function(key, values) {
        result = {region: []};
        values.forEach(function(x){ result.region.push(x); });
        return result;
    },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
).results[0].value.region
```

Or using group (thanks to @Travis for adding this one):

```
db.foo.group({
  reduce: function (curr, result) {
    result.regions.push(curr.region);
  },
  initial: { regions: [] }
})[0].regions
```

**Note**

Using each of this methods you have to remember about [BSON Document Size Limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size)

Comment: I went ahead and added another option I could think of instead of making my own answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely closer.  But I end up with:

    {
        "0" : "NW",
        "1" : "SW"
    }

which I would still have to process to get a simple array.

Comment: @Travis great. I was about to do it myself :)

Comment: @kidbrax Could you explain? With documents like in the example none of this should give you `{ "0" : "NW", "1" : "SW"}`. What version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: yeah, nevermind.  My db client(Robomongo) was outputting it that way for some reason.  when done directly in the mongo shell, it worked fine. thanks!